# Как можно оптимизировать получение списка дочерних элементов "дерева"

Tags: java, алгоритм, оптимизация, дерево

Есть дерево вида

```
                               a
                              /|\
                             b c d
                            /\    \
                           e  f     g
```

Как можно получить список дочерних элементов по какому-то элементу (Передали в ф-цию "a", а получили массив из [b,c,d,e,f,g]. Передали "b" получили [e,f]) Элемент имеет идентификатор родителя, а так же является ли он "контейнером"

```
 protected void fetchChildElements(Elem parentElem, List<Elem> childElems, List<Elem> allElem) {
        for (Elem childElem : allElem) {
            String parentElemId = childElem.getParentElemId();
            if (parentElemId != null && parentElemId.equals(parentElem.getId())) {
                if (childElem.getElemCategory() == DeviceCategory.CONTAINER) {
                    fetchChildElements(childElem, childElems, allElem);
                }
                childElems.add(childElem);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: А стандартный обход в глубину чем вам не угодил? Или у элемента нету ссылок на дочерние элементы?

Comment: @VladD Да, родитель не знает о дочерних

Comment: Но у вас есть список _всех_ элементов? Похоже, вам нужна топологическая сортировка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну например так.

Давайте построим отображение элемента в его родителя. Это можно сделать один раз, и обновлять таблицу при каждом изменении дерева. Или просто использовать вместо функции `String getParentElemId()` функцию `Elem getParentElem()`.

Получится вот что:

```
Map<String, String> mapToParent = 
    Arrays.stream(allElements)
          //.collect(Collectors.toMap(Elem::getId, Elem::getParentId)); // WTF Java?
          .collect(HashMap::new,
                   (m, elem) -> m.put(elem.getId(), elem.getParentId()),
                   HashMap::putAll);
```

Теперь чтобы проверить каждый элемент, достаточно пройтись по цепочке родителей, и искать в ней нужное:

```
String rootId = "b";
Arrays.stream(allElements)
      .filter(elem -> {
          String curr = elem.getId();
          while (curr != null && !curr.equals(rootId)) curr = mapToParent.get(curr);
          return curr != null; })
      .forEach(elem -> System.out.println(elem.getValue()));
```